# CountreExample generation in KodKod

Tags: alloy

I have just switched to working with **KodKod** I am still trying to understand it. I have wrote a program to help me understand I succeeded to see if the solution is *SATISFIABLE* or *UNSATISFIABLE* .

I want to be able to see the **CountreExample** like we normally do in Alloy, I found the Method *proof()* of the type *solution* but it always returns **null** .

I want to know if there is a way to return the CountreExample or not.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this examples of Alloy API usages: https://github.com/kaptoxic/alloy/tree/master/src/edu/mit/csail/sdg/alloy4whole